# Updating a many-to-many relationship in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have two Models

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Permissions = new HashSet<Permission>();
    }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
 }
```

AND

```
public class Permission
{
    public Permission()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

The joining table is created automatically and I cant see the ef model. When I want to update a user's permission, I am doing this in controller

```
    user.Permissions.Clear();
    foreach (var permissionID in userDTO.Permissions)
    {
       var permission = _context.Permissions.Find(permissionID.PermissionID);
       if (permission != null)
       {
          user.Permissions.Add(permission);
       }
     }
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

However when I try to clear the existing permissions of a user and inserting new permissions for user, I get an error: Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'permissionuser.PRIMARY'

How do I fix this?

Comment: *when I try to clear the existing permissions* -- Please show how.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to clear user permissions that they are existed in your new set.

1. Check the previous permissions and remove that are not existing any more

```
user.Permissions= user.Permissions.ToList();

 for (var i=0; i< user.Permissions.Count; i++)
 {
    var exist= userDTO.Permissions.Any(i=> i.PermissionID=user.Permissions[i].PermissionID);
 if (!exist) user.Permissions.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

2. Now add new permissions

```
    foreach (var permission in userDTO.Permissions)
    {
        var existedPermission= user.Permissions.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.PermissionId=permissionID.PermissionID;
        if (existedPermission== null)
        {
             var newPermission = _context.Permissions.Find(permission.PermissionID);
             if (newPermission != null) user.Permissions.Add(permission);
        }
    }
```

Comment: and how can i delete permission here so if ealier permissions were [1,2'3] and new ones are [2,3] how will this work?

Comment: @Aishwarya Yes, you are right ,  I know it and preparing an updated unswer now.

Comment: line user.Permissions[i].PermissionID : has error, Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ICollection<Permission>

Comment: still same error. the code is not compiling

Comment: i know how to compile. What i'm saying is your code has syntax errors and wont compile.

Comment: @Aishwarya I am sorry but what I mean is that SO is not a free coders resource. Nobody will do the whole coding for you. I gave you the several hints how to manage your problem, but if you don' t know how to code nobody can help you.